# jQuery.unbind deletes wrong handler created using $.proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, microsoft-ajax

I have JavaScript class:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var ClientControl = function () {
    //some instance-specific code here
};

ClientControl.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.documentClickedDelegate = $.proxy(this.documentClicked, this);
        //this.documentClickedDelegate = Function.createDelegate(this, this.documentClicked); // from MicrosoftAjax
    },

    bind: function() {
        $(document).bind("click", this.documentClickedDelegate);
    },

    unbind: function() {
        $(document).unbind("click", this.documentClickedDelegate);
    },

    documentClicked: function() {
        alert("document clicked!");
    }
};

var Control1 = new ClientControl();
Control1.initialize();
var Control2 = new ClientControl();
Control2.initialize();

Control1.bind();
Control2.bind();

Control1.unbind();
//Control2`s documentClickedDelegate handler, if created with $.proxy, already is unbound!

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the problem is, when **unbind()** method of FIRST **Control1** object is called, it unbinds BOTH **documentClickedDelegate** handlers of both objects, if they are created with **$.proxy()** method.
So jquery event system thinks that these handlers are same, despite different contexts passed to $.proxy() method.

If **documentClickedDelegate** handlers are created with **Function.createDelegate** - MicrosoftAjax Library`s method, everything workds fine. Handlers are different.

Turned out that **$.proxy** creates identical proxy functions for different contexts passed. From official site:

> "Be aware, however, that jQuery's event binding subsystem assigns a
>   unique id to each event handling function in order to track it when it
>   is used to specify the function to be unbound. The function
>   represented by jQuery.proxy() is seen as a single function by the
>   event subsystem, even when it is used to bind different contexts. To
>   avoid unbinding the wrong handler, use a unique event namespace for
>   binding and unbinding (e.g., "click.myproxy1") rather than specifying
>   the proxied function during unbinding. "

Which in my case shoudn`t be done, because namespaces separate type-specific events, not instance-specific.

Here are screenshots, where you can see, that **$.proxy** creates handlers with identical **GUID = 1**, and **Function.createDelegate** creates handlers with DIFFERENT GIUDs: **guid = 1 and guid = 2**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So when deleting one in first case, it deledes both, which should NOT be done!

My question is: is there any analog in jquery to Function.createDelegate? I don`t want to use whole another MicrosoftAjax library for only one feature. 
Or maybe any general solution to this problem - how to tell jquery that handlers are different. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need to namespace the events. Simple example:

```
var counter = 0;

ClientControl.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.documentClickedDelegate = $.proxy(this.documentClicked, this);
        this.num = counter++;
    },
    bind: function() {
        $(document).bind("click.proxy" + this.num, this.documentClickedDelegate);
    },
    unbind: function() {
        $(document).unbind("click.proxy" + this.num, this.documentClickedDelegate);
    },
    documentClicked: function() {
        alert("document clicked!");
    }
}
```

Here's a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/LtuNe/1/). Click anywhere on the document and you get one alert. Without the namespacing you get 2.